# Velocity and many objects in model

Tags: java, velocity

I'm trying to send email using velocity templates here is my template

```
    #set ($subject = "new  message in system $message.mode")
#set ($adress = "@email.com")
#set ($from = "$user.login$adress")

    #set ($to = "$interlocutor.login$adress")
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
        <body>
            <h3>hi you have new message.</h3>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and how i add elemts to model

```
model.put("user", interviewer);
    model.put("interlocutor", interlocutor);
    model.put("message", mode);
```

everything is great except when i print it with

```
System.out.println((String)velocityContext.get("to") + " " + (String)velocityContext.get("subject") +" " + (String)velocityContext.get("from")+ " ");
```

i recive

```
$interlocutor.login@email.com new  message in system $message.mode testlogin@email.com
```

So it looks like velocity coudl handle only one object in model, others are invisible for engine, do you have clue whats wrong?

Comment: It looks like "interlocutor" does not have "login" and "message" does not have "mode".

Comment: that is correct answer

Comment: How You declare `model` ? Consider put one Map into velocity context and operate on the map.